# ¿Porque al traspasar rut como foranea de la tabla empleados a la tabla estudios me la reconoce como invalida?

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Porque cuando intento traspasar la clave foranea la cual es rut que esta dentro de la tabla empleados hacia estudios esta me dice que es invalida? adjunto imagenes de el error y las tablas.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS(
  2  RUT CHAR(10),
  3  NOMBRE VARCHAR(10),
  4  APELLIDO1 VARCHAR(15),
  5  APELLIDO2 VARCHAR(15),
  6  DIRECC1 VARCHAR(25),
  7  DIRECC2 VARCHAR(20),
  8  CIUDAD VARCHAR(20),
  9  PROVINCIA VARCHAR(20),
 10  COD_POSTAL VARCHAR(5),
 11  SEXO VARCHAR(1) CHECK (SEXO IN ('H','M','h','m')),
 12  FECHA_NAC DATE);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE ESTUDIOS(
  2  UNIVERSIDAD NUMBER(5),
  3  ANO NUMBER,
  4  GRADO VARCHAR(3),
  5  ESPECIALIDAD VARCHAR(20));

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_empleados PRIMARY KEY (RUT);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE ESTUDIOS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_estudios PRIMARY KEY (UNIVERSIDAD);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE ESTUDIOS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLEADOS_ESTUDIOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
  3  REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(RUT);
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLEADOS_ESTUDIOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
                                                  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "RUT": invalid identifier


SQL> ALTER TABLE ESTUDIOS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESTUDIOS_EMPLEADOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
  3  REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(RUT);
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESTUDIOS_EMPLEADOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
                                                  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "RUT": invalid identifier


SQL> EDIT
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  ALTER TABLE ESTUDIOS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESTUDIOS_EMPLEADOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
  3* REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(RUT))
SQL> /
REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(RUT))
                         *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Comment: Hola Sebastian. Por favor no uses imagenes que no nos sirven para poder copiar y probar tu SQL. Usa texto formateado por favor.

Comment: ok lo añadire en un momento.

Comment: Pero te diré que creo que no entiendes bien lo que significa crear un foreign key constraint. El hacer esto no crea la columna `RUT` en tu tabla `estudios`. Tu tienes que crear la columna `RUT` de antemano en esa tabla, y luego puedes establecer la relación entre las 2 tablas.

Comment: pero amigo si eso ya esta hecho en la tabla empleados, dentro de la tabla empleados yo cree la columna RUT, por lo tanto deberia estar bien

Comment: Si lees mi comentario, no cuestiono que la columna exista en la tabla `EMPLEADOS`. El problema es la tabla `ESTUDIOS`. No puedes crear una relación entre ambas tablas si la columna no existe en ambas tablas. En este caso, la columna no existe en la tabla `ESTUDIOS`, de allí viene tu error.

Comment: ¿Entonces la solución seria que al estar creando la tabla estudios yo ingrese la columna RUT en ese instante, para despues agregarle RUT como clave foranea?

Comment: Así es. Te deje una respuesta al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una relación entre 2 tablas, necesitas que existan las columnas correspondientes en ambas tablas.

En tu caso, según la sentencia siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE ESTUDIOS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLEADOS_ESTUDIOS FOREIGN KEY (RUT)
REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(RUT);
```

... estás tratando de establecer una relación entre `ESTUDIOS` y `EMPLEADOS` basado en la columna `RUT`.

Pero el problema es que esa columna no existe en la tabla `ESTUDIOS`. Necesitas agregarla a esa tabla primero:

```
CREATE TABLE ESTUDIOS(
UNIVERSIDAD NUMBER(5),
ANO NUMBER,
GRADO VARCHAR(3),
ESPECIALIDAD VARCHAR(20),
RUT CHAR(10)); -- agrega la columna RUT
```

Luego podrás crear la llave foránea sin problema.

Como información adicional, es generalmente una buena idea definir un índice en la columna al que se le define una llave foránea, en este caso `ESTUDIOS.RUT`.

También noto que ninguna de tus columnas están marcadas `NOT NULL`. Sería bueno revisar eso.

Comment: ahh genial amigo te agradecere eternamente la ayuda :)

Comment: ahh si pero eso es porque tengo que seguir los parametros de la guia que me envio mi profesor a hacer y en ella dice que solo en algunas tablas tengo marcarles not null y en otros casos priorizo el CHECK, el DEFAULT y el UNIQUE.